# Did frequentist statistics try to squash Bayesian ones?

Tags: bayesian, frequentist, history

From http://www.bayesianphilosophy.com/dont-ban-p-values/:

> When Frequentists dominated statistics from about 1930 to 1990 or so, they engaged in every kind of draconian, career destroying, and underhanded method possible to squash Bayesians.

I wonder at which degree this claim is exaggerated ? (I hope it is exaggerated...) I heard/read this kind of claims several times with various degrees of intensity and I wonder whether it is completely baseless or comes from specific striking articles/attacks/periods/... ?

Comment: I can't see how it could not be an exaggeration. But it does strike me as typical of the things you see written in the perennial Frequentist-Bayesian squabbling.

Comment: @gung Agreed but is it completely baseless ? or does it come from specific striking articles or attacks ? (thks udpate my question)

Comment: TBH, I have no idea. My prior would be that a lot of papers were rejected in cases where the author thought the rejection was unfair, & that there probably were some isolated cases where there really was an egregious action, but that these were interpreted as typical of what was 'always' happening behind closed doors.

Comment: Wow. Personal opinion here, but taking everything from that blog with a heavy grain of salt. Entertaining, but a little off the rails.

Comment: Although it has been recommended that this thread be made CW, it seems to me that it could have a factual answer supported by appropriate (historical) research and authorities and as such does not seem to require CW status.  However, any polemical replies that attempt to rehash the Frequentist-vs-Bayesian argument would be inappropriate for our format.

Comment: If "career destroying" was true then there would have been law suits in USA.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about statistics but about statisticians and can only be usefully answered as history.

Comment: @whuber Perhaps a candidate for history of science.SE?

Comment: There is nice discussion on some of this controversy in this paper by Gelman and Robert. http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/feller8.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be an interpretation (and possibly exagerration) of the less tolerant side of Fisher's personality (in his role as frequentist advocate in chief). For example see Joan Box's comment of Fisher's personality in

http://ije.oxfordjournals.org/content/32/6/938.full

and note it is quoted by someone who is very well disposed towards Fisher.

Fisher rejected Harold Jeffreys' early development of Bayesian statistics, and attacked it vigorously.The book "Interpreting Probability: Controversies and Developments in the Early Twentieth Century", by David Howie (Cambridge University Press, 2002) apparently has coverage of a lot of the back and forth that went on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and reference. I lend a copy of Howie book, it looks interesting. I hope I will find the time to read it.